Integrating Code back into Original Document
I have a large document with the opportunity to input my code chunks, but I am unsure how to integrate my code into the document. The original document is in .ipynb format and I have the code I am writing in Google Colab and downloaded the sections as .ipynb. My employer would like me to integrate the code and comments into the original document and mentioned using HTML, but I am unsure how to do that.
I have the individual code chunks saved as both .ipynb and .py files and have successfully inputted the results of the result (ex. "10%" or "blah blah blah") but I cannot seem to integrate my code into the document.

do you mean like this ?  https://sites.google.com/view/python-programming-01/home
